# How do I select only the month end date from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am new to SQL, here is my problem.
I have a table with daily dates:

Date:

```
20190101
20190102
20190103
  .
**20190131**
20190201
20190202
20190203
  .
**20190228**
20190301
20190302
20190303
  .
**20190331**
```

I want to select only the month-end dates, what would be the code to do that?
thanks
I am using MS SQL Studio.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Welcome. It would be great if you could include the code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

One method in standard SQL would be:

```
select t.*
from t
where extract(month from date + interval '1' day) <> extract(month from date);
```

Date/time functions vary significantly by database, so the exact functions might not match your database.  However, the idea is simple:  add one day and see if the month changes.

Comment: ANSI SQL has `interval '1' day`.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you could do:

```
select date
from mytable
where date = date_trunc('month', date) + interval '1' month - interval '1' day
```

---

**Edit**

In SQL Server, you can just use [`eomonth()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Given a date, this functions returns the corresponding end of month, which you can compare against the date. So:

```
select date
from mytable
where date = eomonth(date)
```

Comment: `date_trunc` is no ANSI/ISO SQL function.

Comment: @jarlh: I was not aware of that. So is there some date truncation function in ANSI SQL?

Comment: You can  `extract()` year, month etc.